# UnityEvent not getting invoked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

Basically I'm iterating throwgh an array of sliders and if the slider matches some conditions, firing the onValueChanged event, where I have some listeners attatched.

```cs
if(xValue != 0f)
            {
                horizontalPressed = true;

                Slider slider = elements[index];

                float step = slider.maxValue * increaseStepPercent;

                float value = slider.value + step * xValue;

                slider.value = Mathf.Clamp(value, slider.minValue, slider.maxValue);
                slider.onValueChanged?.Invoke(slider.value);
            }
```

This is the code I'm using to invoke the event. I've already checked with the "GetPersistentMethodName" that the method I want to trigger is subscribed to the event and I already checked that the specific line of code of the invoke method is getting called.

So, that leaves me with no clue. Any ideas?

PD: The valueof the slider is changing, the only thing missing is the onValueChange to be triggered.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you debug with a breakpoint and make sure the correct slider is being invoked and if `onValueChanged` is actually not null in this specific moment?

Comment: Hi Hugo, thank you for the answer. In fact, I just realized that the probles is on the editor, because I just made a build and it works just fine...